# Adding character litterals perl (very simple)

Tags: perl, printing, character, printf

If anyone wants some quick rep here you go :).

How can I add character litterals like I can do in C.  For example

```
 print 'A' + 1
```

The above should print 'B' since ASCII 'A' + 1 gives ASCII 'B'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chr(ord('A') + 1)`. Perl doesn't have a character type, it has a string type. And a string doesn't behave numerically as an ASCII value. You want `ord` to convert it to a numeric codepoint and `chr` to convert it back.

Comment: As a special case you can `++` string.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov, the magic of `++` doesn't behave like doing arithmetic on C's `char` type. Doing `char foo = 'Z' + 1` in C and `my $foo = 'Z'; $foo++;` in Perl will have very different results.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu, but of course. Since it is "special" indeed, it's logic is more complex and it's better to read docs before using it. BTW, there's also no corresponding `--`.

Answer (score 2):

If you store strings in variables then [you can increment them](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement).

```
$ perl -E'$a = "A"; say ++$a'
B

$ perl -E'$a = "abacaa"; say ++$a'
abacab

$ perl -E'$a = "Z"; say ++$a'
AA
```